# ¡Otro idioma! :)

Tags: riddle, language, haiku

Courtesy to [@question_asker](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28926065#28926065).

> Muchas preguntas
>   Muchos pesos por bueno
>   Tú estás aquí.

¿Qué soy?

(I believe this is a rather simple one.)

Comment: I've locked the comments here due to a significant amount of arguing about the use of Spanish in this puzzle. If you want to discuss this (calmly), please [do so on this meta question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4670/riddle-containing-other-languages-than-english).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the answer:

> Puzzling Stack Exchange. Muchos preguntas = Many questions -> There are many questions on this site. Muchos pesos por buenos = Many pesos for good -> I'm assuming pesos is referring to rep and you get a lot for good questions. Tu estas aqui = You are here -> you are on puzzling stack exchange if you are reading this

Comment: You did it! YAY!!

Comment: You didn't do it. Gordon did it. @You

Comment: Being honest I google translated the second line to double check por buenos didn't have a different meaning then for good ones since my spanish is a bit rusty

Comment: The Spanish of the OP is probably as rusty as yours (otra idioma, "for good" what?)

Comment: I'm Spanish and can't say this made too much sense (at least in Spanish from Spain)...